# jQuery Combobox with autocomplete & anchor tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that is a combobox with autosuggest via Ajax but an anchor tag should be listed at the end of the suggestions with the text="Click here if no suitable results were found"(selfexplanitory).
Does such a thing exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of tweaking the of the standard [jQueryUI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) you can create something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/dF3Sb/

Good luck!